# reset the TTL in redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

How to reset the TTL on the redis hash key?
There is already TTL on the redis say 60 sec and now I want to make it 300 sec  using spring boot.

Comment: there is event coming on kafka and based on that I want to reset the ttl on hash key

Comment: `expire hash-key 300`